# Magento Emails are not going through gmail and hotmail on (sendmail, nginx, varnish, phpfpm 7.o)

Tags: magento2, email, nginx, send-mail

Facing issue with the emails. emails are not going through gmail and hotmail but it's working for the business domains of Google G suite app. I'm using Sendmail function on nginx and even tried with postfix too with no help yet.

Comment: and error response is...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module to setup gmail smtp. I use it to test my transactional emails : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/